# execute multiple command with jsch session and channelexec

Tags: java, unix, apache-kafka, jsch

I struggled to get this working but eventually got the script to execute a command (executing a sh script) on a remote unix server. I am trying to execute a second command and keep getting an error either with creating  a new channel or using the same.

```
       try {


            ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);
            PrintStream out= new PrintStream(channel.getOutputStream());
            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();

            BufferedReader scriptReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            scriptOutput = scriptReader.readLine();

            sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((scriptOutput = scriptReader.readLine())!= null) {
                sb.append(scriptOutput + "\n");
```

This is the first snippet of the channel execute which works fine. Now the next method snippet is called immediately after consuming the above inputstream:

```
      try {

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          command = new_command;
          ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command);

          InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
          channel.connect();
          BufferedReader scriptReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          scriptOutput = scriptReader.readLine();

            //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for(int c=0; c < consumerList.size(); c++){
           ....
```

Now this returns the following error:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: channel is not opened.
```

Now if I create a new channel with the same session I get a null response from returned stream. I did test the command in the remote shell and it works fine:

```
      int counter = 0;
      Channel channelII = session.openChannel("exec");

      try {

          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          command = new_command;
          ((ChannelExec) channelII).setCommand(command);

          InputStream in = channelII.getInputStream();
          channelII.connect();
          BufferedReader scriptReader= new BufferedReader(
           new InputStreamReader(in));
          scriptOutput = scriptReader.readLine();
```

the second command is the following and I want to be able to repeatedly execute it for different consumer groups:

```
/usr/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 
    192.xxx.xx.xxx:9092 --describe -group consumergroup1
```

EDIT:

response of second command:

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  
   LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           
  CLIENT-ID
   output.influxDB    1          94919           2781796         
    2686877    -                                                 -                              
   -
   output.influxDB    0          94919           2781798         
    2686879    -                                                 -                              
   -
   output.influxDB    2          94918           2781795         
    2686877    -                                                 -                              
    -
```

Comment: What are the 2 commands you are trying to execute remotely?

Comment: You can set both commands in one line separated by `\n`. For eg : `command = cd /home \npwd \n`

Comment: What is the first command? Does it somehow relate to the latter command or not? Did you try reading an error stream?

Comment: I need the output from the first command to run the second: first command - kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 192.xxx.xx.xxx:9092 --list --> this will give me the list of consumer-groups which I can then use individually for the next command - kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 192.xxx.xxxxx:9092 --describe -group ????

Comment: OK, but the second command **works** even without the first, right? (has you known the group)

Comment: So did you try reading the error stream? + What exactly do you mean by "null response"? Do you mean an empty response? Or do you really mean the `null`? What output do you expect? What does `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` output?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - yes the second command works fine when including any group. No I did not read the error stream as I figured the command was executed correctly but reading the inputstream returns "", empty.

Comment: what's with the negative vote?

Comment: I do not get your last comment. So would you try reading an error output? And what is your question now? Do you want to understand why you get an empty output even if the command succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Nicholas and Martin for their responses. I figured out what was wrong and wanted to post an answer as I do realize that little things like this do crop up for us 'dumb' programmers out there who ask ridiculous questions that incur negative votes. The output for the second command was returning a warning / error response in the first line and by not including the following I was not seeing that and reading the next line was empty. I know it's stupid and should have figured this out before posting because that is the point of this site: post questions that are beyond the knowledge of others. But since I should have innately  known this:

Anyway ensure the following line is included:

```
  ((ChannelExec)channelII).setErrStream(System.err);
```

and also read the stream with a loop and not just test with reading the first line.

```
     while ((scriptOutput = scriptReader.readLine())!= null) {
                sb.append(scriptOutput + "\n");
          }
```

I hope this can at least be a lesson to some if not a solution.

Comment: As mentioned before, though, it's generally easier to use existing Kafka API to fetch this information

Comment: The `setErrStream` makes sense only if Cisco has very small error output buffer. Though indeed, in general, you need to read both error and standard output. See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/37528319/850848 - Though even in that case you should not get `null` from `readLine`, it should rather hang.

Comment: @NicholasK how? you can go ahead and post your comment as an answer and I would accept that.

Comment: @vbNewbie : I guess I should've been more clear. Upvote another answer of mine. I meant that as a joke, but wouldn't hurt any way ;) Also din get your question clearly so thought of leaving just a comment.